# NullPointerException in the foreach statement

Tags: arraylist, foreach, nullpointerexception

I am trying to run the program but I keep getting the problem NullPointerException and it says that the problem is in the first for statement "for (ArrayList arrlist : arlt)". Does anybody knows what is the problem? Thank you very much.

```
public static ArrayList<String> LinesToBeShifted(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arlt) {
        ArrayList<String> shift = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (ArrayList<String> arrlist : arlt) {
            for (int i = 0; i < arrlist.size(); ++i) {
                shift.add(getString(arrlist));
                arrlist = wordShift(arrlist);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get NullPointerException in the for loop the problem could be that arlt is null

Comment: That's what I thought too but I have never declared arlt as a null before.

Comment: @GeraldTukseferi with the code that you posted I cannot see where you actually pass arlt to LinesToBeShifted method. Maybe you can post the code where you initialize ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arlt.